# How to use a form text component multiple times through CRX DE in CQ5

Tags: aem

I want to add a form text component multiple times in a page and give different id's to them in CQ5.

Answer (score 1):

The default form text component doesn't provide option to specify an id, rather it generates one itself.

The id that is generated is the **formId_elementName**, where formId is the id of the form which is present in the form start component(defaults to "new_form") and the elementName is the value that is provided in the Element Name field of the form text component.

But, in case you would like to provide the authors, the ability to add their own id's to the form start component, then one possible way would be to override the default form text component.

Add an additional field to the dialog box of the form text component called id and use that value in the jsp as id for the input field. But be cautious when providing this functionality, as the authors may forget to update the id fields appropriately, there by resulting in many text fields having the same id.